# Showing bootstrap modal with jquery delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that is supposed to kick off a process and also show a modal. The problem that I am having is that the modal doesn't show until the function that it is called with (upload()) is finished. Since the modal is supposed to be a step indicator, this defeats the purpose. Is this the normal behavior and if so is there a way to show the modal before the function finishes executing?

```
<button id="btnUpload" onclick="jQuery('#mymodal').modal('show');upload();">Save</button>
```

I have also tried putting the jquery to show the modal as the first line of upload() which didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
<button id="btnUpload"data-toggle="modal" 
  data-target="#myModal"
  onclick="upload()">Save</button>
```

Doing so should call the modal almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your upload function does, it is hard to say what is happening exactly.

You could however use the following, which isn't exactly the best solution, but it should work

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnUpload").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
    upload();
  }).click(function(){
    $("#mymodal").modal("show")
  })

})

function upload(){
  alert("do the thing");
}
```

with the html being just

```
<button id="btnUpload">Save</button>
```